# Disable windows live messenger fade in/out

Tags: windows-live-messenger

I applied the 'security update' and msn version changed. I dont like it.

Is there a way i can disable the fade in/out? It happens when you click on > to show/hide contacts.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see any simple way to do that. Why not download an [**old version**](http://www.oldversion.com/MSN_Messenger.html) ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem caused by ATI Catalyst (or AMD Vison Engine Control Center) that can be fixed by going into your 3D graphics settings and disabling Morphological Filtering.